# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

It is my first app that I am trying to build in Iphone and I have some problems. Although I have read similar threads here I was not able to find the answer.I want to show popoverview controller on my button click.but unable to do. i am getting exception mention in question title above below are my files
.h file

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;
@property (nonatomic,strong) SecondViewController *popOverView;
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)Getcompany:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *popoverview=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popover"];
    self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverview];// getting exception in this line
    popOver.delegate=self;
    [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];





}
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not available on an iPhone.  From the documentation: "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception."

Comment: means i want to select a value from popover and store in text box ??? which another control i may use ?

Comment: You can push or present another view controller, depending on your app logic.  You could have a hidden text field that gets displayed when the button is pressed if there's space for it....

Comment: ahan i waz thinking on button click i will show a popover through in which diffrent colours are present and selecting one colour it will set in text box.. which control will i use ???