# On iOS7 iPad 1x/2x mode only Facebook & Twitter icon is missing in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

- My application is only for iPhone and when I run same application on iPad in 1x & 2x mode then UIActivityViewController does not showing facebook & twitter icon also mail icon is not proper. Although the functionality is working properly.
- As per configuration respective accounts are already configured in Settings.
- This issue only occurs on iPad but works fine on iPhone.

  ```
  - (void)onShare:(id)sender {

  UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"World Cup! 2015",[UIImage imageNamed:@"WC15"]] applicationActivities:nil] ;

  [activityView setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePrint,nil]];

  [self presentViewController:activityView animated:YES completion:nil];
  ```

  }

> Only Facebook & Twitter icon missing.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is we need to use *UIPopOverViewController for iPad* and *UIActivityViewController for iPhone*.

Please look out this question for detailed description : [UIActivityViewController crashing on iOS8 iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644054/uiactivityviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios8-ipads)

Here's the code you need to use to resolve this issue:

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Test",nil] applicationActivities:nil];

//if iPhone
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
//if iPad
else {
    // Change Rect to position Popover
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

**NOTE :- UIPopoverController is not available on an iPhone. From the documentation: "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception (If your app is iPhone only then this exception comes)."**

Reference Link :- ['NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865306/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-uipopovercontroller-initwithcontentview)

Might this helps you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I have only iPhone app and if you see iPhone app's UI render on iPad so, **if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)** also fails this condition in iPad(Try if you want).This is not correct answer. I had changed to customized UIView with animation like UIActivityController cause sharing activity items are constant.

Answer (score 0):

As solution for above issue, I just created customized `UIView` with required animation and for items each different implementation. The only solution I explored.